# psycopg2 dynamic insert query issues, syntax error at or near Identifier

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm writing a program to extract a lot of data from another source and record it in a Postgres database.  I need a function that takes in the destination table and a dictionary with variable fields to be added and then inserts it as appropriate.  It seems like it should be simple enough, but I'm running into problems generating the insert query.  The examples I've found online are either partial, outdated, or simply don't work when I modify them for my data.

Here's a simple version I've put together to work it out.  I've tried a lot of variations of this, so it's probably not as clean as it should be at this point.  It feels like there's something really simple that I'm just missing, but if so I'm just not seeing it.

```
def insert_record():

    table = "test"
    record = {"name": "Jack", "id": 1}
    fields = record.keys()
    values = ", ".join(str(n) for n in record.values())

    query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});".format(
                    sql.Identifier(table),
                    sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, fields)),
                    sql.SQL(",").join(sql.Placeholder() * len(fields))
                    ))
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    print(query.as_string(connection))
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, (values,))
        connection.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    cursor.close()
```

This returns the error:

```
syntax error at or near "'test'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO Identifier('test') (Composed([Identifier('name')...
```

It looks like it's not actually formatting the query for whatever reason, since the as_string function also returns the unformatted:

```
"INSERT INTO Identifier('test') (Composed([Identifier('name'), SQL(','), Identifier('id')])) VALUES (Composed([Placeholder(''), SQL(','), Placeholder('')]));"
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or better ways to handle dynamic queries in general?

**edit**: Here's my import statement

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras, Error, sql
```

Comment: import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras, Error, sql

Comment: Note that the 'format' you are invoking is the 'format' of plain string type, not the 'format' of the sql.SQL.  I don't think that that is what you want.  Do you have misplaced parentheses?

Comment: Duh, that's it.  I knew it was probably something trivially easy that I was just too close to see.  Thanks for being a second pair of eyes.

Comment: i ran into the same issue :)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the function `.format()` from the object string, you must call the `.format()` function from `sql.SQL()` object class.

```
query = sql.SQL("INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});").format(
                sql.Identifier(table),
                sql.SQL(",").join(map(sql.Identifier, fields)),
                sql.SQL(",").join(sql.Placeholder() * len(fields))
                )
```

Ref: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html?highlight=literal#module-usage